# Can I transfer a call to another number mid-call (on my iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, call

I would like to transfer a call (mid-call) to another number. Is it possible?

Comment: Like another cell number?

Comment: The answer is carrier and plan dependent.  Typically this feature is included more often in business plans than it is in personal plans.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is add another number to the call once you’ve started it, then you can talk using the other phone number that you added.

The only thing is you cannot hang up on he original number once you add the second number or else both numbers will be disconnected.

Comment: Not true of all plans and carriers.  Transfer and drop can be offered, although typical personal plans won’t have it business plans may offer.

Comment: @Tyson iOS has the feature built in to add people, so I don’t think it depends on the carrier/plan

Comment: “Transfer and drop” can be available however, which is what the question asks.  It’s not clear cut, as your answer makes it.

Comment: My sister in law has it on her work iPhone, after she adds a party, she gets both an “end call” and a “drop” button.  “Drop” allows her to leave the conversation while the call continues between the other two parties.  True call transfer.

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time by pushing ## ...it tells me I am transferring the number and then I put in the number to route to... only, it has do be done within 20 seconds or you have to start over and push ## again

The final step is done by the phone... you wait until it disconnects you

This works on my iPhone X with ATT family plan